# Why is a child form detected after it has been closed?

Tags: c#, forms

I have a child form that part of the code is closed as follows:

```cs
this.Close();
```

Then in another part of the code I look for all the open children forms to close them in the following way:

```cs
foreach (Form formChildOpen in this.MdiChildren)
{
   if (!formChildOpen.Name.Equals("Sell"))
   {
      formChildOpen.Close();
   }
}
```

but when debugging, in the search of open forms, appears the form that I previously closed.

What I need is to determine if the form has been closed to open it, a pseudocode would be like this:

```cs
foreach (Form formChildOpen in this.MdiChildren)
{
   if (!formChildOpen.Name.Equals("Sell"))
   {
      formChildOpen.Close();
   }
   else
   {
      formChildOpen.Show();
   }
}
```

Obviously it would not work correctly because in some other part of the code the form called "Sell", is not closed and when executing the above code, an additional form was opened to the one that is already open.

Any idea or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: A cumbersome solution is to activate a flag in the event when the "Sell" form is closed and with that flag to determine whether or not to open the form.

Answer (score 0):

using those hashsets and the shown and closed events you can track which

form is open and whichone is closed

```
    private readonly HashSet<Form> _closedForms = new HashSet<Form>();
    private readonly HashSet<Form> _openForms = new HashSet<Form>();

    private void FormOnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _openForms.Remove((Form) sender);
        _closedForms.Add((Form) sender);
    }

    public void FormOnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _closedForms.Remove((Form)sender);
        _openForms.Add((Form)sender);
    }
```

but foreach form you have to assign these eventhandlers with

```
        form1.Closed += FormOnClosed;
        form1.Shown += FormOnShown;
```

Comment: Error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0079 The event 'Form.Closed' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= 196 Active

Answer (score 0):

We're looking for the best instance of the form named Sell to show (if there is already one visible, then use that one):

```
Form frmSell = null;
foreach (Form formChildOpen in this.MdiChildren)
{
   if (!formChildOpen.Name.Equals("Sell"))
   {
      formChildOpen.Close();
   }
   else
   {
      if (formChildOpen.Visible || frmSell == null)
          frmSell = formChildOpen;
   }
}
if (frmSell != null)
    frmSell.Show();
// else
// consider creating a new instance of form Sell here
```